# get the name of properties of a table using string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get the name of properties of a table-data model in entity framework.
I have this code

```
 var properties = context.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                        BindingFlags.Public |
                                        BindingFlags.Instance);
```

All i want is to include this code in a method like the one following in order to have a string variable that defines the table-model:

```
 MyMethod (string category)
 {
     var properties = "category".GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                    BindingFlags.Public |
                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
   ......
   ......

 }
```

Is it possible? Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Assembly.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) method to do this. Your code would look something like this:

```
// Don't forget to null-check the result of GetType before using it!
// You will also need to specify the correct assembly. I've assumed
// that MyClass is defined in the current executing assembly.
var properties = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("My.NameSpace.MyClass").
    GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance);
```

You can also use [Type.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

```
var properties = Type.GetType("My.NameSpace.MyClass").
    GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!However i get this error when using the above code: cannot access non-static method 'GetType'  in static context

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fix for that, and an alternative method (the Type.GetType method is probably simpler thinking about it)